# How can I show or hide menu options in Master page depending user roles and permissions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, user-roles

I'm trying to control the menu options depending user roles and permission, after the user login. I saved the user in session and then I get the roles and permissions from data base, then I want to show the main page which is a Master with the menu options how can I do it without using javascript, I'm using c# asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Roles.IsUserInRole(roleName))
{
    // show controls accordingly
}
else
{
    // hide controls accordingly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
   //show menu
}
else
{
   //hide menu
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this with server tags on the .aspx side.

```
<% if (User.IsRole("Administrator")) { %>
    <div>Admin Stuff</div>
<% } %>
```

or you could handle it all server side and wrap the content in PlaceHolders and show/hide them accordingly

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="AdminPlaceHolder" runat="server">
    <div>Admin Stuff</div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

---

```
AdminPlaceHolder.Visible = User.IsRole("Administrator");
```

Comment: I'm going on the fact that I have no idea how OP is managing the user session